# Fork bomb in a while loop in C, that occurs after exiting a program

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, fork

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid = 0;
    int forever;
    static char s; //Uses simply s in the while loop, press s once for each process to
//terminate each process
    //char *s; This can't work because it always points to the start of a char array.
//I don't know why. int * doesn't do that.
    pid = fork();
    if(pid>0)// a child cannot see it's own process ID so pid would be 0 if it was the
child
        printf("This is the parent.\n");
    else if(pid == 0) printf("This is the child.\n");
    while(s != 's'){//One quote is a character, two quotes is a char array
        forever = fork();
        if(forever>0)
            printf("Parent process\n");
        else printf("Child process\n");
        s = getchar();//I tried making this *s but it causes a segmentation fault
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

This is causing a problem. When I execute the program from terminal, I can exit the program by entering 's' once for each process, and the terminal goes back to normal. Or so it appears. When I press the "up" arrow when in terminal, I go into an endless loop and get a fork bomb. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use the debugger (`gdb`) and `strace` ?

Comment: To be fair, using debugger or strace to examine fork bomb bug might not be trivial...

Comment: the 's' value is being used before it is set, so it could be anything, including the termination char 's'.

Comment: getchar() returns an integer, so this line: static char s; should be: int s; (no need for the static qualifier)

Comment: the check for 's' is only killing/exiting the current process.  All other processes continue to run/multiply, forever.  by the time the user can enter an 's' there could be thousands of processes running, each process doing nothing but creating more processes.  So the system is going to crash sooner or later (probably sooner) irregardless of hitting the up arrow on the keyboard

Comment: the code fails to check for the event of a fork() failing (return code < 0), so after failures begin happening, each currently existing process keeps right on looping, trying to start even more processes (most of which will fail to fork()).

Answer (score 1):

Change `s` to

```
int s = 0;
```

Because `getchar` returns int and you do need it. Also no point making it static (no harm either here, just bad/unusual style). Note that you now need initialization, unlike when it is static.

Then check `getchar` return value for error/EOF, `<0` and terminate on that also. That should fix the fork bomb, because it is most likely caused by `getchar` starting to return immediately with error. Add prints to see what is happening, especially print the error message or EOF status.

Also you should check `fork` return value for errors as well, just in case.